# python - community detection(clustering) using kernighan-lin algorithm in networkx package

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, networkx

Networkx, python package, has a kernighan-lin bisection algorithm.
But that algorithm is to divide a graph into clusters A and B(bisection).

#### However I want to divide a graph into clusters A, B, ... (multi-section) naturally using kernighan-lin algorithm.

In another python package, community(http://perso.crans.org/aynaud/communities/), it has an algorithm I want(multi-section), but it has been implemented by another algorithm(Louvain hueristices).

I must use kernighan-lin algorithm to get multi-section clusters.

Is there a way to implement multi-section clustering using kernighan-lin algorithm?

Or, How can I implement multi-section clusters using kernighan-lin algorithm by myself?